# SQL_VARIANT and DATETIME2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-variant

Lets say you have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [Value] [sql_variant] NOT NULL
)
```

And lets insert some DATETIME2 values:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]
(
    [Value]
)
VALUES
(
    SYSUTCDATETIME()
)
```

Now, lets see the results:

```
SELECT
    [Value],
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY([Value], 'BaseType') AS BaseType
FROM
    [dbo].[Test]


Value                     BaseType
-----------------------------------
2019-11-25 19:39:43.274   datetime2
2019-11-25 19:43:49.735   datetime2
```

Why do the values get truncated?

Answer (score 4):

When working with `sql_variant`, you need to be specific about the datatype you wish to return; otherwise SQL Server will infer the display format. The data, however, has not been truncated. If you try the following, for example, you'll see you get a `datetime2(7)` as the result for `Value_DT2`:

```
SELECT [Value],
       CONVERT(datetime2,[Value]) AS Value_DT2,
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY([Value], 'BaseType') AS BaseType
FROM [dbo].[Test];
```